# What is the best way to route data from multiple Google spreadsheets into one master sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an initial Form responses data sheet that separates to individual spreadsheets based on different work streams of my business. I now need to bring all of this data from the individual Google sheets to one Master sheet. Data will continue to add to the individual sheets and will need to be updated in the recombined Master as the data is added to the multiple docs.

```
function importVariations() { // This function knows about the documents and requests that data.
var documents = [
'1f_2KYg8l_Pnrruc6o2OnmSvz6JUml5eMboRTdSO1PZM', 
'1Vbg7iUgtJtO15W0Bc9x22ImCepfs7F3B3GfnQSbZ1EM',
'1eIK2tiiB28b-wP8so_zbcdNKrF-v0OuXwG4BG1hlI98',
'1jJ6sfzfoCtvFo-zHiQR7vvhukBQC8aiO1ZJEHz5sKwI',
'1EiP0wYAAYpG1VBDq2aaeuwifB2__ZkmwOP7cKdkqWBg',
'17kv6rZtLbMo3dS7vuJNONkH0LWBrfwr_qBi1skeo4WY',
'1bQHXHcSTri_AgBLR932KU6Y0NNr_PIAYJY-KFMKRmFk',
'1jGJqmp-4SbgpMokxv6pyDkbkVSJnlhGYiM82PUQB3mo',
'14oAR3GPW8RKGzmXKhuwBW6CrHBq8xYu_KACP1zRFjlU',
  ];

var sheetsToPostTo = ['1dXyxH5XrqRn9mLXEAOglmg-hFSER0LJa2Df6C5YRtJg'];
var allData = getAllData(documents); // get all the data and store in variable

for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToPostTo.length(); i += 1) { // loop through all master sheets and post allData
    postAllData(allData, sheetsToPostTo[i]);
    }

}

function getAllData(documents) { // concatenate all data and return
var allData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i += 1) { // loop through all documents
    allData = allData.concat(getRawData(documents[i])) // get raw data for each document loop through
    }

return allData; // return all data
}

function getRawData(sheetID) { // get raw data for a sheet, remove headers and return just data
var data = SpreadsheetApp.openbyid(sheetID).getsheetbyname('Responses').getDataRange().getValues();

data.shift();
data.shift();

return data;
}

function postAllData(data, sheetId) { // posts data passed to the sheet id passed
SpreadsheetApp
    .openbyid(sheetId)
    .getsheetbyname('1dXyxH5XrqRn9mLXEAOglmg-hFSER0LJa2Df6C5YRtJg')
    .getRange(3, 1, data.length(), data[i].length())
    .setValues(data); // post all of the data to the sheet
}
```

Getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function openbyid in object SpreadsheetApp. (line 34, file "getdata")

Additionally, `var sheetsToPostTo` doesn't highlight as a variable, why is this?

Comment: In `.getRange(3, 1, data.length(), data[i].length())` i is not defined in this line in postAllData().  Have you tried using the debugger in the script editor.

Comment: Hey there, Thanks for your reply and advice about how to ask on SO. Thought that I explained what I'm trying to accomplish in my initial verbatim but to be clear, I want to bring multiple Google Sheets into one Master Sheet on a continuous basis. Thank you for the insight on the capitalization--totally overlooked that!

Answer (score 0):

Case matters.  It's `openById()` same problem with `getSheetByName`.  Generally, if a variable doesn't highlight as a variable in script editor it means there is an error in the code somewhere.

- [Reference1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))
- [Reference2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))